# Conditional Entropy if outcome is known

Tags: conditional-statements, theory, entropy

I have a question about Entropy and Information Flow. Suppose that X = {-1, 1}; meaning that it can be either -1 or 1, and the following assignment for Y:

```
Y := X * X
```

My question is that the value of Y, after the assignment, will always be 1. If X = -1, then Y=1 and if X = 1, then Y= 1. Knowing this, can I still assume that the conditional entropy H(X/Y) = 0, because knowing X will always tell you the Value of Y. On the other hand, the conditional entropy H(Y/X) = 1.0 because knowing Y will not give me the value of X. 
Am I thinking in the right direction? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are partially correct, though it seems like you are rather "swapped" in your notation and your definition.

```
H(X|Y) is entropy of X given Y rather than entropy of Y given X.
```

Also, you should try to look at the condition here more carefully. Since you have a very clear relationship between X and Y, that means Y = f(X). And in that situation, just as you say, the conditional entropy is **always** 0 (yet you are swapped in your notation). Thus it should be

```
H(Y|X) = 0
```

On the other hand, if you have Y, you completely have no clue of what is X and both -1 and 1 have **equal** probability. So in this case

```
H(X|Y) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Ian. I really appreciate you clear this up for me. :)

Comment: Glad that my explanation can be of any help. This kind of topic is uncommon in the SO, though. Typically what you show here is code and your problem, though you may ask some more conceptual stuff too.

Comment: No, no, I do not mean that way. I mean I checked the number of people asking with tag `entropy` here is very rare. Only 270 out of 10 millions questions.

Comment: Just one last question. If H(X/Y) means that information will flow from Y -> X and H(X/Y) information flows from X -> Y. Correct?

Comment: In the stricter sense X|Y simply means X given Y, this notation is used everywhere is probability and statistic. So in that sense, loosely translated to information flow, since Y comes first, it can be translated as a flow Y then X.

Comment: You are welcome. You can see more common practice in the help centre of the site.